# Greatest common divisor / euclidean algorithm linear combination proof

Tags: proof-writing, divisibility

Consider integers $m$ and $n$, not both 0. Show that gcd$(m,n)$ is the smallest positive integer that can be written as $am + bn$ for integers $a$ and $b$.

I'm confused on what exactly to do--I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the question. I know that using the euclidean algorithm backwards will provide me with an $a$ and a $b$ such that $am + bn = gcd(m,n)$. But I'm not sure how to prove that it is the smallest positive integer.

Comment: If you know how to calculate gcd(m,n) via the euclidean algorithm, then you know that gcd(m,n) | m and gcd(m,n) | n. Don't you? Now, if we have d = am + bn for some integers a and b, then we must also have that gcd(m,n) | d. Why? How does this help you in answering your question?

Comment: Thank you. $am$ is a multiple of $gcd(m,n)$ and $bn$ is a multiple of $gcd(m,n)$. In class, we said that a multiple of $k$ + a multiple of $k$ is a multiple of $k$. Thus, $d$ is a multiple of $gcd(m,n)$. However, I'm not sure how that means $gcd(m,n)$ is the smallest positive integer that can be written as $am + bn$. It does mean that $gcd(m,n) * k = d$ by the division algorithm. What am I missing? =(

Comment: That's the argument that $d$ is a multiple of the gcd, and hence greater than or equal to the gcd. One needs a separate argument to show that $d$ is less than or equal to the gcd. Try this: divide $m$ by $d$, yielding a quotient $q$ and a remainder $r$. Argue that if $r>0$, then $d$ wasn't really the least integer of the form $am+bn$ after all. So $r=0$ and $d$ divides $m$; similarly, $d$ divides $n$. Why can you then conclude that $d$ is less than or equal to the gcd?